# Print items from within a list of dicts

Tags: python

How can I go about printing a specific value within this array in Python? For example I want to just print the profession of "Joe" which would be "teacher". I have tried multiple ways to do this but I keep getting back an error and if I just use print(data[1]) I get back all of the information about Joe instead of just the occupation. I have also tried using a for loop but can't seem to reproduce what I am wanting. I have checked answers on here but haven't seem to find any that will solve my issue.

```
data = [
    {
        'name': 'Mike',
        'age': 34,
        'profession': 'Lawyer',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Joe',
        'age': 21,
        'profession': 'Teacher',
        'country': 'Portugal'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Jane',
        'age': 18,
        'profession': 'Musician',
        'country': 'Canada'
    }
]
```

Comment: From `print(data[1])` to `print(data[1]['profession'])` is one logical step which addresses your problem.

Comment: @etch_45 my bad I just fixed it

Comment: @skuzzy yes, this is exactly what I want and what I was missing. Thanks so much...If you want the points put this in the answers as you were first to answer and I'll mark it as correct. Thanks again.

Comment: The `{key, value}` pairs are inconsistent in your data. The third entry has `description` vs `profession` for the first two.

Comment: @etch_45 ah my bad, another copy and paste error.... I changed some of the info as I didn't want to share personal info. thanks.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. You can mark the comment as helpful too I guess.

Comment: Typos are a pain for sure.  Check out my answer if it helps any.

Comment: @etch_45 i did, thanks! and thanks for the edit too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `print(data[1])` to `print(data[1]['profession'])` is one logical step which addresses your problem.

`data[1]` retrieves a `dict` type element which is a collection of key-value pairs. To access a `value` belonging to a `key`, the `[]` operator can be used with the `key` on the dictionary.

```
dict_item['key']     # here dict_item is data[1] and 'key' is 'profession
```

You will need to put this inside of an iterator if you wish to process all entries of your list.

Answer (score 2):

This will just print the profession manually.

```
print(data[1]['profession'])
```

Else you can take name as input

```
name = input("Enter your name: ") 
print(name) 
for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i]['name']== name :
        print(data[i]['profession'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to get a specific item from a dictionary?

```py
print(data[1]['profession'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have uniform `{key, value}` pairs in your data, try this method:

```
>>> for el in data:
...     print('Name:', el['name'], 'Profession:', el['profession'])
... 
Name: Mike Profession: Lawyer
Name: Joe Profession: Teacher
Name: Jane Profession: Musician
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
for i in data:
    if i['name'] == 'Joe':
        print(i.get('profession'))
```

Here you could change `'Joe'` with any other name like `'Mike'` and could also change `'profession'` with any other key like `'country'`.

Comment: So that one can search by taking the name as input. Suppose it's a large list then it will be much easier to search by name instead of using index values.